# finstrument-functions-exclude-function-list appears to not handle commas properly

Tags: c++, gcc, compilation, instrumentation

Attempting to compile with finstrument-functions and exclude a template function with multiple template parameters, using the \ method to escape commas (as described for exclude-file-list [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.4.5/gcc/Code-Gen-Options.html)) fails to properly disable instrumenting the function passed.

GCC command used:

```
gcc -finstrument-functions -finstrument-functions-exclude-function-list='test<float\, int>' main.cpp -o a.out -O0
```

Above creates a binary file with the "test" function instrumented. Assembly snippet and main.cpp file included below

gcc -dumpversion returns "6.2.0", above command run on red hat enterprise linux, version 7.4

Contents of main.cpp:

```
template<class T, class U>
T test(int a, T b){
    int res = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < 1000; i++){
        res += i;
    }
    return(res);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv){
    float a = test<float, int>(argc, 1.0);
    return(0);
}
```

objdumped output for "test" function:

```
000000000040059f <float test<float, int>(int, float)>:
  40059f:   55                      push   %rbp
  4005a0:   48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
  4005a3:   48 83 ec 20             sub    $0x20,%rsp
  4005a7:   89 7d ec                mov    %edi,-0x14(%rbp)
  4005aa:   f3 0f 11 45 e8          movss  %xmm0,-0x18(%rbp)
  4005af:   48 8b 45 08             mov    0x8(%rbp),%rax
  4005b3:   48 89 c6                mov    %rax,%rsi
  4005b6:   bf 9f 05 40 00          mov    $0x40059f,%edi
  4005bb:   e8 70 fe ff ff          callq  400430 <__cyg_profile_func_enter@plt>
  4005c0:   c7 45 f8 00 00 00 00    movl   $0x0,-0x8(%rbp)
  4005c7:   c7 45 fc 00 00 00 00    movl   $0x0,-0x4(%rbp)
  4005ce:   81 7d fc e7 03 00 00    cmpl   $0x3e7,-0x4(%rbp)
  4005d5:   7f 11                   jg     4005e8 <float test<float, int>(int, float)+0x49>
  4005d7:   8b 55 f8                mov    -0x8(%rbp),%edx
  4005da:   8b 45 fc                mov    -0x4(%rbp),%eax
  4005dd:   01 d0                   add    %edx,%eax
  4005df:   89 45 f8                mov    %eax,-0x8(%rbp)
  4005e2:   83 45 fc 01             addl   $0x1,-0x4(%rbp)
  4005e6:   eb e6                   jmp    4005ce <float test<float, int>(int, float)+0x2f>
  4005e8:   8b 45 f8                mov    -0x8(%rbp),%eax
  4005eb:   66 0f ef c9             pxor   %xmm1,%xmm1
  4005ef:   f3 0f 2a c8             cvtsi2ss %eax,%xmm1
  4005f3:   f3 0f 11 4d e4          movss  %xmm1,-0x1c(%rbp)
  4005f8:   48 8b 45 08             mov    0x8(%rbp),%rax
  4005fc:   48 89 c6                mov    %rax,%rsi
  4005ff:   bf 9f 05 40 00          mov    $0x40059f,%edi
  400604:   e8 17 fe ff ff          callq  400420 <__cyg_profile_func_exit@plt>
  400609:   f3 0f 10 45 e4          movss  -0x1c(%rbp),%xmm0
  40060e:   c9                      leaveq 
  40060f:   c3                      retq
```

I expected the test function to not be instrumented, but it is. Does anyone know why this is?

[Compiler explorer example](https://godbolt.org/z/54GUAS)

Comment: Hi @Scheff, the comma needs to be escaped because otherwise gcc treats everything after it as a separate function substring,so if I replace "test<float, int>" with "test<float, float>", the function is still not instrumented as the substring "test<float" matches the test function.

Comment: Nice catch. I didn't try with "test<float, float>" and came to the wrong conclusion. :-(

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anyone comes by this way, both this and finstrument-functions-exclude-function-list not respecting namespace parts of a function are bugs, and I have filed against both. Hopefully a fix will be implemented soon (working on one currently).

[Namespace / class mishandling](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=90816)

[Comma mishandling](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=90809)